What are the tests done before a satellite/payload is ready
A lot of things go into consideration before launching a payload into orbit. And obviously, a lot of tests take place before the final launch. I would like to know of all the tests that take place and how/why they are done, I'm hoping this would also allow me to understand what a spacecraft payload usually goes through during flight.

The SE system is based on question and answer format. Broad spectrum requests such as this are contraindicated. If you can pin your interest to a single question, you'll find it easier to get an answer that does not deteriorate into a discussion. Take a look at https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for some helpful hints and requirements. One specific point in the above link that is lacking in your question is your previous research.

Which tests are done or to what extend they are conducted depends a bit on the mission profile. A payload to the ISS undergoes a different testing than does an Earth observation satellite than does an interplanetary probe (different environments). Vibration tests might be conducted differently based on the chosen launcher.
The minimal set seems to be

vibration test. The main purpose is to qualify the payload to survive the vibrations of the rocket launch
environmental / thermal (vacuum) test. This tests the survivability of the equipment in the forseen environment. Especially appropriate cooling and heating of electronics (and possibly some mechanical hardware as well) are the issue here.

further one might want to conduct

static load tests
acoustic tests (which somewhat might overlap with vibrations)
EMC (electromagnetic conformity)
magnetic cleanliness
functional test(s) of all your subsystems and the overall system, especially a communications test

The results of all the tests are reviewed in the Flight readiness review and flight acceptances review upon which the payload is allowed to become just that: payload.
Some of the might (especially mechanical and thermal) might be conducted with an alternate set of hardware, or conducted more harshly with an alternate set of hardware.
See also:

https://www.planetary.org/articles/how-we-test-spacecraft-before-launch
https://www.space.irfu.se/seminars/20180523-Cripps-HW_Project.pdf
https://aerospace.org/sites/default/files/maiw/TOR-2010(8591)-20.pdf
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710019569/downloads/19710019569.pdf


Add to that a wealth of subsystem and component level testing that may or may not as well: radiation, single event effects, hypervelocity impact testing, vacuum outgas testing, atomic oxygen degradation, arcjet testing (for reentry heat shields), shock loading, etc
